# Create an external table in access with outlook contacts programmatically

Tags: ms-access, vba, outlook, object-model

I'm not sure if this is possible, but i would like to create an external table in access with outlook contacts **programmatically**. I've searched in the Microsoft Access object model, but couldn't find a method or property that enables you to do so.

I need this for synchronizing contact persons between outlook and an application I'm building. I know there are other ways, but this option seems to be the simplest one.

Comment: It's not clear for your question what you're doing. Do you have contacts in Access and contacts in Outlook and you want to synchronize them, or do you want to user your Outlook contacts in Access?

Comment: Basicly i want to have my Outlook contacts in an Access table. This makes it alot easier for me to synchronize contacts between an application i'm building and Outlook. And i wanted to do this programmatically because i want to create the Access database in my application based on the user that's logged in. Different users have different profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example how to do this in visual basic.

```
Set td = New TableDef
td.Connect = "Outlook 9.0;MAPILEVEL=Postbus - Hello World|;" & _ 
                "PROFILE=Microsoft Outlook Internet Settings;" & _ 
                "TABLETYPE=0;TABLENAME=Contactpersonen;" & _ 
                "DATABASE=C:\DOCUME~1\********\LOCALS~1\Temp\"
td.SourceTableName = "Contactpersonen"
td.Name = "TestContactpersonen"
db.TableDefs.Append td
```

Comment: How does this synchronize Access data with Outlook?

Comment: This is how you programmatically define a table in an Access database that connects with Outlook contacts. Exactly what i wanted. After defining this table i can use queries to determine which contacts needs to be updated, etc... Hopefully this clarifies my question and answer.